# random row from diapason (1: n) in groups sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, random

I need select random row from Table using groups and order, but random's row number in group  should not be more then constant (for example const = 3).
What I mean:

```
id time  x
1  10:20 1
1  11:21 9
1  16:14 4
1  08:13 8 
2  01:20 2
2  21:13 0
```

For id=1 rows could be:

```
id time  x
1  10:20 1
1  11:21 9
1  08:13 8
```

BUT not 
`1  16:14 4` because in order by time  it's local number more than 3
for 
Id= 2 - any row

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? MySQL?

Comment: DBMS -  PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte as  (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by id ORDER BY RANNDOM()) as rn
    FROM myTable
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT distinct on (id) *  
FROM (select
 row_number() over (partition by id order by time ) as up_lim
from tab1) as a
WHERE row_number <= 3
ORDER by id, random() ;
```